# Parsing a file from first char in each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to group a file by the first character in each line of the file.

For example, the file:

```
s/1/1/2/3/4/5///6
p/22/LLL/GP/1/3//
x//-/-/-/1/5/-/-/
s/1/1/2/3/4/5///6
p/22/LLL/GP/1/3//
x//-/-/-/1/5/-/-/
```

I need to group everything starting with the first `s/` up to the next `s/`. I don't think `split()` will work since it would remove the delimiter.

Desired end result:

```
s/1/1/2/3/4/5///6
p/22/LLL/GP/1/3//
x//-/-/-/1/5/-/-/

s/1/1/2/3/4/5///6
p/22/LLL/GP/1/3//
x//-/-/-/1/5/-/-/
```

I'd prefer to do this without the `re` module if possible (is it?)

**Edit:** Attempts:

The following gets me the values in groups using list comprehension:

```
with open('/file/path', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

groups = ['s/' + group for group in content.split('s/')[1:]]
```

Since the `s/` is the first character in the sequence, I use the `[1:]` to avoid having an element of just `s/` in `groups[0]`.

Is there a better way? Or is this the best?

Comment: How about using regular Python loop? You can get lines as list of lists with f.readlines() and later iterate over them and wait for first `s/`

Comment: Do you want the end result in a new file?

Comment: @Artur That returns an iterable of each line though, the lines are relative to each other; so everything between the `s/` need to be grouped.

Comment: @AdiC No, a local variable is fine since the data will be parsed even further (by the `/`'s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first line of the file starts with `'s/'` you could try something like this:

```
groups = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('s/'):
            groups.append('')
        groups[-1] += line
```

To deal with files that don't start with `'s/'` and have the first element be all lines until the first `'s/'`, we can make a small change and add in an empty string on the first line:

```
groups = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('s/') or not groups:
            groups.append('')
        groups[-1] += line
```

Alternatively, if we want to skip lines until the first `'s/'`, we can do the following:

```
groups = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('s/'):
            groups.append('')
        if groups:
            groups[-1] += line
```

Comment: @bendl if you're working from a file, `for line in f` will retain newlines

Comment: The `groups[-1] += line` produces an `IndexError`. Why are we indexing at `[-1]`?

Comment: @datta my guess is your file doesn't start with `'s/'` - let me try a different approach

Comment: @asongtoruin I've accounted for that, see my edit to your question

Comment: @datta your edit was very specific to the file as it is at present - I've changed it to make it more general.

Comment: @asongtoruin Well it would help if I realized that its `S/'` not `s/`! General solution is clean, like it a lot.